# JMX MBean registration using Spring on a standalone JVM

Tags: java, spring, jvm, jmx

Following various example configurations from Spring documentation as well as some forums on the Internet, my application context file looks like:

```
<beans>
    <bean id="dH" class="abc.def.ghi.DH">
        <constructor-arg>
            <value>0</value>
        </constructor-arg>
        <property name="num" value="100"/>
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter" lazy-init="false">
            <property name="beans">
              <map>
                    <entry key="bean:name=dH1" value-ref="dH"/>
              </map>
            </property>
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.jmx.support.MBeanServerFactoryBean"/>
</beans>
```

I'm running this without any container and on plain JVM. I'm able to connect to my process via JConsole but the MBean doesn't show up. However registering the bean programmatically exposes it successfully.

```
MBeanServer mbeanServer = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
DH dh = new DH(0);
mbeanServer.registerMBean(dh, new ObjectName("bean:name=dH1"));
```

I've tried playing with the Spring configuration without success. I think the bean is not registering to the already running MBean server that was accessible from ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer().
Any ideas on the issue?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In addition to defining an [MBeanServerFactory](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jmx/support/MBeanServerFactoryBean.html) bean (as [Nicholas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/43786/nicholas) noted in their [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9164399/649852)) using ...

```
<bean class="org.springframework.jmx.support.MBeanServerFactoryBean">
    <property name="locateExistingServerIfPossible" value="true" />
</bean>
```

... you need to tell the [MBeanExporter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jmx/export/MBeanExporter.html) what to manage:

> If a bean implements one of the JMX management interfaces, MBeanExporter can simply register the MBean with the server through its autodetection process.
>
> If a bean does not implement one of the JMX management interfaces, MBeanExporter will create the management information using the supplied MBeanInfoAssembler.

Assuming your `abc.def.ghi.DH` class does not implement any JMX interface, try defining your `MBeanExporter` as:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter" lazy-init="false">
    <property name="assembler">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.jmx.export.assembler.MethodNameBasedMBeanInfoAssembler"
        >
            <property name="managedMethods">
                <list>
                    <value>getNum</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="beans">
        <map>
            <entry key="bean:name=dH1" value-ref="dH"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Looking at the OpenJDK 7, update 2, build 21 [`DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u2/jdk/file/24e42f1f9029/src/share/classes/com/sun/jmx/interceptor/DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java) source, line 898 creates a [`DynamicMBean`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/management/DynamicMBean.html) for regular objects:

```
DynamicMBean mbean = Introspector.makeDynamicMBean(object);
```

I haven't debugged it, but I bet `mbeanServer.registerMBean(dh, new ObjectName("bean:name=dH1"))` eventually calls `DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject()`, which creates a `DynamicMBean` for you and properly registers your standard `JavaBean` properties' setters and getters.

---

Here are some test files that work using Spring Framework 3.0.5 and Oracle HotSpot Java 1.6.0_24. After setting your `CLASSPATH` environment variable, just run `javac *.java` and `java Main` and use VisualVM (or similar application) to connect to the running java application to see the registered MBeans.

**ac.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd"
    default-lazy-init="true"
>
    <bean id="test" class="Test" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.jmx.support.MBeanServerFactoryBean">
        <property name="locateExistingServerIfPossible" value="true" />
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter" lazy-init="false">
        <property name="assembler">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.jmx.export.assembler.MethodNameBasedMBeanInfoAssembler"
            >
                <property name="managedMethods">
                    <list>
                        <value>getVal</value>
                        <value>setVal</value>
                    </list>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="beans">
            <map>
                <entry key="bean:name=Test" value-ref="test"/>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**Test.java**:

```
public class Test {
    private String val = "";
    public String getVal() {
        return val;
    }
    public void setVal(String v) {
        val = v;
    }
}
```

**Main.java**:

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
public class Main {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ac = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("ac.xml");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000 * 60 * 5);
        } catch (final Throwable t) {}
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for digging this out @Dan. When Spring context is loaded or even the dh is created using the context the Introspector line is not even executed. However registering the bean manually does call the same line. I don't think Spring is trying to register the bean with these configurations. Something must be missing...

Comment: This works for me using Spring 3.0.5 and a simple JavaBean with one property getter/setter; I can connect to my simple test app with VisualVM and see the test MBean that was registered using the `MBeanExporter` bean definition I provided. Try breaking your scenario down to a simple form, get that to work, then build it back up to what you currently have and see where your issue lies.

Comment: Using Spring 3.1.0 I tried with your provided XML with and without -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote as program option, still no luck.
I'm loading the context in the following manner:
BeanFactory factory = new XmlBeanFactory(new ClassPathResource("/application-context.xml"));
and then loading the intended MBean as:
factory.getBean(DH.class);
I know this sounds naive but is there a way we can match our complete XMLs and simple program structure?

Comment: Thanks a bunch @Dan. It was the way the beans were getting initialized :|. I was using BeanFactory whereas using the ApplicationContext did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with the MBeanServerFactoryBean.

From the [javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.9/api/org/springframework/jmx/support/MBeanServerFactoryBean.html):

> By default, MBeanServerFactoryBean will always create a new
>   MBeanServer even if one is already running. To have the
>   MBeanServerFactoryBean attempt to locate a running MBeanServer first,
>   set the value of the "locateExistingServerIfPossible" property to
>   "true".

Try this config:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.jmx.support.MBeanServerFactoryBean">
    <property name="locateExistingServerIfPossible" value="true" />
</bean>
```

**=================================================**

Try specifying the MBeanServer in the exporter bean:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter" lazy-init="false">
    <property name="beans">
        <map>
                <entry key="bean:name=dH1" value-ref="dH" />
            </map>
        </property>
        <property name="server" ref="MBeanServer" />
</bean>
<bean id="MBeanServer" class="org.springframework.jmx.support.MBeanServerFactoryBean">
    <property name="locateExistingServerIfPossible" value="true" />
</bean>
```

**========================================================================**

Ok, let's take the brute force approach and acquire the platform MBeanServer directly:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter" lazy-init="false">
    <property name="beans">
        <map>
                <entry key="bean:name=dH1" value-ref="dH" />
            </map>
        </property>
        <property name="server">
            <bean id="MBeanServer" class="java.lang.management.ManagementFactory" factory-method="getPlatformMBeanServer"/>
        </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks for the other suggestions @Nicholas. Though trying them both didn't register the MBeans as well.